# How to tell which NuGet packages will be published/deployed

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a .NET Core project and am trying to determine which NuGet packages will need to be deployed/published with my app during the post-build event (sorta like record keeping and such for my own benefit).

At first I thought I could read something like the project file, something in obj, or whatever else is in the project's directory, but I cannot see anything that stands out (I also don't know what I'm looking for exactly, so that doesn't help..).

For example, the particular package I noticed trouble with first was `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`, which has dependencies. Most get published along with it, such as `System.Security.Permissions.dll`, **but** I noticed that `System.Security.AccessControl` is nowhere to be found in my publish directory, despite it even being mentioned in the [app].deps.json file (which is an optional file anyway, AFAIK).

So, what my question boils down to is: Is there any sort of project file, nuspec metadata, etc. that I can read to know whether a particular dependency actually gets deployed/published?

My fallback option is to call `dotnet publish...` to some temp location and just examine the files that end up there, but I'd prefer something that does not require this.

I've only seen this with Core so far. Normal Framework apps seem to deploy all, but I'm not sure if that's just because of the dependencies I tested with, or it's a cause of the project type.